# AR Camera shakes at beginning for few seconds

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia

The AR Vuforia camera shakes/jitters in beginning when the game is loaded for 5 seconds. I noticed it because the AR objects move out of the place and their positions to few meters away and then they stay there instead of their starting positions. This is because the camera moves away from its original position. Is there a way that the camera stays in the position that is pre -defined in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you have not placed your image target as a child of AR camera

I was having the same issue but after placing my image target under the AR camera in hierarchy the issue was resolved

hope this helps...